# In Android SDK, does calling bindService() with the same service class from multiple different activities create new instances of that service?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-service

Based on the documentation it would seem it does not, but I haven't found an explicit statement saying so.

Comment: I don't think so. Look @ http://androidxref.com/5.1.1_r6/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/content/Context.java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For all services, whether bound or not, there is only ever at most one instance of it - subsequent calls to `bindService()` (or `startService()`) will only trigger the existing Service, should it already be running.